# valgrind output points to gfortran library

Tags: valgrind, gfortran

I run valgrind-3.10.0 to search for memory leaks in my fortran program. I'm using gfortran-4.9.0 to compile on OS X 10.9.5. From what I can tell from the below output, the memory leak is in a gfortran library. Am I correct? If so, is there anything that I can do?

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==30650==     in use at exit: 25,727 bytes in 390 blocks
==30650==   total heap usage: 34,130 allocs, 33,740 frees, 11,306,357 bytes allocated
==30650== 
==30650== Searching for pointers to 390 not-freed blocks
==30650== Checked 9,113,592 bytes
==30650== 
==30650== 72 (36 direct, 36 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 52 of 84
==30650==    at 0x47E1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:300)
==30650==    by 0x345AB0: __Balloc_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==30650==    by 0x345CF6: __i2b_D2A (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==30650==    by 0x34362E: __dtoa (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==30650==    by 0x36A8A9: __vfprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==30650==    by 0x3912DA: __v2printf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==30650==    by 0x376F66: _vsnprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==30650==    by 0x376FC5: vsnprintf_l (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==30650==    by 0x3674DC: snprintf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==30650==    by 0xE2F6D: write_float (in /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib)
==30650==    by 0xE53A4: _gfortrani_write_real (in /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib)
==30650==    by 0x3FA9999999999999: ???
==30650== 
==30650== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30650==    definitely lost: 36 bytes in 1 blocks
==30650==    indirectly lost: 36 bytes in 1 blocks
==30650==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30650==    still reachable: 316 bytes in 7 blocks
==30650==         suppressed: 25,339 bytes in 381 blocks
==30650== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==30650== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==30650== 
==30650== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 15 from 15)
--30650-- 
--30650-- used_suppression:     34 OSX109:6-Leak /usr/local/lib/valgrind/default.supp:797 suppressed: 13,656 bytes in 252 blocks
--30650-- used_suppression:      1 OSX109:1-Leak /usr/local/lib/valgrind/default.supp:747 suppressed: 2,064 bytes in 1 blocks
--30650-- used_suppression:     13 OSX109:7-Leak /usr/local/lib/valgrind/default.supp:808 suppressed: 7,181 bytes in 78 blocks
--30650-- used_suppression:     11 OSX109:10-Leak /usr/local/lib/valgrind/default.supp:839 suppressed: 1,669 bytes in 29 blocks
--30650-- used_suppression:     10 OSX109:9-Leak /usr/local/lib/valgrind/default.supp:829 suppressed: 609 bytes in 15 blocks
--30650-- used_suppression:      5 OSX109:5-Leak /usr/local/lib/valgrind/default.supp:787 suppressed: 144 bytes in 5 blocks
--30650-- used_suppression:      1 OSX109:3-Leak /usr/local/lib/valgrind/default.supp:765 suppressed: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==30650== 
==30650== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 15 from 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could very well be a bug in the gfortran library.

Your best bet would be to reduce this to a self-contained test case and report it to the gfortran developers at fortran@gcc.gnu.org or to submit a bug report at http://www.gnu.org/bugzilla .